# Render a template instead a success_url in form_valid with FormView django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

As the title says: I need to render a template after submitting a form, this form is handled with `FormView` with the method `form_valid`. With the method `post`, I can render a template after submitting it but maybe with `form_valid`, I can do it in the cleanest way.

How can I do it?

Comment: No, you don't need to do this. Redirect to another url which renders this template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, I have tried this but does not solve my problem, because this template only may be displayed if the user fill the form, if the user knows the url of that template can access to that template only typing the url

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The default implementation of `form_valid` is to redirect to `success_url`, you only need to override it to render some page. Here is the example.

```
class ChangePasswordPage(FormView):
    template_name = 'core/password-change.html'
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        messages.success(self.request, "Your password is changed")
        return render(self.request, 'core/password-change-success.html', self.get_context_data())
```

Comment: I wonder why this option is not supplied by default and you have to use such a hacky way to achieve this. I mean who wants their users to access `/success/` directly without a context? Who wants to create ignore rules for search engines to skip this page? Who wants to create another view and add another url to urlconf if you can just simply render a success template. Why this option is not default, I think I am missing something

Comment: @Dany I wondered about the same thing, as I didn't want to define an url with a load of parameters from my form just to pass the data to a new view. It matters if the user reloads the success page: without the redirect, it will resubmit the form (which may or may not cause problems in your use case).